# message box in tkinter is not showing any output

Tags: tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
def s():
    messagebox.showinfo("Oh hi")
    
  
w = Tk()

s = Entry()
s.grid(row =0, column =1)

l = Label(text = "What is your name?" )
l.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

button = Button(text = "Submit", command = s )
button.grid(row = 1,column = 3)
w.mainloop()
```

My message box option is not showing me the output? why so? It is not giving me the error but when I click the submit button it is not doing what it is supposed to do?

Comment: This code won't run.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to `showinfo` is the title of the window. If you want the information to be inside the dialog, assign it to the `message` parameter.

```
messagebox.showinfo(message="Oh hi")
```

---

Unrelated to the question that was asked, the code you posted won't ever display the message in `s` because you've redefined `s` to be an entry widget rather than your function.

Comment: Oh thanks,  did not notice it. thanks for the suggestion.